# Detecting symbolic link

Tags: go, symlink

My goal is to determine if a file I have is a folder or a symlink to a folder.
With the way I tried it I'm unable to detect the difference here.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    linkPath := "./myLink"

    // with golang
    f, _ := os.Stat(linkPath)
    fmt.Println(f.Mode().String())

    // ls -la
    out, _ := exec.Command("ls", "-la", linkPath).Output()
    fmt.Printf("%s", out)
}
```

The output on my (Debian) system looks like this: (first letter of each line is important!)

```
drwxr-xr-x
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 7 Nov 16 13:31 ./myLink -> target/
```

So the FileMode in Go seems to detect a directory instead of a symlink, but the `ls` command shows that it actually is a symlink.

I created that symlink with the command

```
ln -s target/ myLink
```

Am I missing something here or why does this not work?

Edit: I'm using go version go1.11.6 linux/amd64

Comment: Stat is not for sysmlinks. Use Lstat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.File.Stat` maps rather directy to the [`stat(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/stat) syscall which, on Unix, follows symlinks.

`lstat(2)` does not follow them (hence the leading `l`), and in the Go standard library there's a matching call: [`os.Lstat`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat).